# How to show a list of article titles

Tags: views, nodes

I am a bit confused. I understand what teaser does(shows the title and a preview and maybe some other things of an article). How do I not show a preview of the article.

I just want title and possibly author. My aim is to have a frontpage/homepage that only shows a list of titles.

I don't like the look of the article preview.

Still sorta new to Drupal hoping for an in depth explanation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If literally all you're trying to do is not show the body in a teaser, Views is totally overkill if you're not already using it elsewhere.

Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE/display/teaser` and hide the body.

Comment: I agree Views is a bit overkill. I just want to change how the teaser is shown. I found it but its taking forever with a loading symbol. Was I suppose to change the trim length?

Comment: Sorry not sure I know what you mean, what's taking forever to load?  In that path above you should be able to drag the body (and any other field) into "hidden".  The title isn't present in the list of fields but it's always included.  Alternatively, if you need more control, you can override the theme and/or preprocess.  Depending on what you override, this can be done as generically as all nodes, only of a certain type, or as specifically as an individual node. See [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440) if you're unfamiliar with the process.

Comment: Yeah i think my drupal installation is just lagging. Ill just do another post if it keeps occuring . thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is the [Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views):

> You need Views if
>
> You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort it
> differently.
>
> You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you
> want to sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
>
> You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain type.
>
> You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display articles
> the way you like.
>
> You want a way to display a block with the 5 most
> recent posts of some particular type. You want to provide 'unread
> forum posts'.
>
> You want a monthly archive similar to the typical
> Movable Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the
> form of "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month,
> and displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts
> for that month. Views can do a lot more than that,
>
> but those are some of the obvious uses of Views.

- create a new view as a Page with Fields
- add whichever fields you want displayed
- assign that page address as the front page under /admin/config/system/site-information

Comment: I agree. Views is the way to go :)